# MySQL: Temporary table storage location

Tags: mysql

I have been reading about temporary tables and how if you exceed tmp_table_size, it is converted on an on-disk MyISAM table.  What I can't find is where that table is stored.  I assume it's the MySQL datadir.  Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is called [`tmpdir`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-files.html) and has a system default of `/tmp`, `/var/tmp` or `/usr/tmp`.

You should note though the paragraph about hidden files. You won't be able to actually see the files/tables on disk during operation. And that `ALTER TABLE` behaves slightly differently.

Answer (score 1):

It should be created in the mysql temp directory, as specified by the `tmpdir` clause in my.cnf